# get the farthest intersection point of ray

Tags: c++, box2d

I want to get the farthest intersection point between two points. But when I do this:

```
RaysCastCallback callBack;
_world->RayCast(&callBack, in.p1, in.p2);
```

then the intersection point would be the closest from p1 to p2.
Is there a way to get the farthest intersection point, or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

The intersection point will only be the closest if your callback makes it so - there is no built-in callback that gives you the closest point by default.

Here is a callback that will record the furthest point intersected.

```
class RayCastClosestCallback : public b2RayCastCallback
{
public:
    bool m_hit;
    b2Vec2 m_point;

    RayCastClosestCallback() {
        m_hit = false;
    }

    float32 ReportFixture(b2Fixture* fixture, 
                          const b2Vec2& point, 
                          const b2Vec2& normal,
                          float32 fraction) {
        m_point = point;
        m_hit = true;
        return 1; // keep going and don't change the ray length
    }
};
```